# "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" errors in table

Tags: tables

I keep getting the above error, can anyone see what is the error?
Thanks.

```
\begin{table*}[h]
\caption{Categorical Review}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|m{4cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{2cm}|m{2.7cm}|m{4cm}|} \hline
 \centering \textbf {\normalsize Paper } & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Type} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Defined Twin} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Actual Twin} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Broad Area} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Specific Area} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Technology} & \hline 
 {\small Bilberg, Malik (2019) \cite{bilberg_digital_2019} } & {\small Case Study} & { \small DT} & {\small DS} & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Smart Factory} & {\small Simulation } \\[0.3cm] \hline
 {\small Chhetri et al. (2019) \cite{chhetri_quilt:_2019} } & {\small Case Study} & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Assembly Line} & {\small AI, Sensors, Simulation } \\[0.3cm]
 \hline
 {\small He et al. (2018) \cite{he_surveillance_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DS } & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Power System } & {\small Simulation, AI, Analytics } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Howard (2019) \cite{howard_digital_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DM } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Product Development } & {\small EDA, Visualisation } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Jain et al. (2019) \cite{jain_digital_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Fault Diagnosis} & {\small Industry 4.0 } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Karadeniz et al. (2019) \cite{karadeniz_digital_2019} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small DS } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Ice Cream Machines} & {\small AR, VR, Industry 4.0, AI, CPS } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
  {\small Kuehn (2019) \cite{kuehn_simulation_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DS } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Smart Factory } & {\small Simulation } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Lu (2019) ( \cite{lu_energy-efficient_2019} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small No Example} & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Smart factory} & {\small Cloud, CPS, Industry 4.0 } \\[0.5cm]
\hline
 {\small Mandolla et al. (2019) \cite{mandolla_building_2019} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small No Example } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Aircraft} & {\small Blockchain, Visualisation } \\[0.5cm]
\hline
 {\small Mawson, Hughes (2019) \cite{mawson_development_2019} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Energy Modelling} & {\small Industry 4.0 }\\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Min et al. (2019) \cite{min_machine_2019} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small DS } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Petrochemical Factory } & {\small AI, Optimisation }\\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Qi, Tao (2018) \cite{qi_digital_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Smart Factory} & {\small Industry 4.0 , AI, Cloud, Big data } \\[0.3cm]
 \hline
 {\small Shangguan et al. (2019) \cite{shangguan_hierarchical_2019} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small DM } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Wind Turbine} & {\small CPS, } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Sivalingam et al. (2018) \cite{sivalingam_review_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DS} & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Wind Turbine } & {\small CPS, Simulation } \\[0.3cm]
\hline
 {\small Tao et al. (2019) \cite{tao_digital_2019} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Smart Factory} & {\small CPS, Industry 4.0, AI } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
  {\small Tao et al. (2018) \cite{tao_digital_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Manufacturing } & { \small Assembly Line} & {\small CPS, Industry 4.0, AI } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Xu et al. (2018) \cite{xu_digital-twin-assisted_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DS} & {\small Manufacturing} & { \small Fault Diagnosis} & {\small CPS, Industry 4.0, AI, Transfer Learning } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small El Saddik (2018) \cite{el_saddik_digital_2018} } & {\small Definition } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Healthcare } & { \small Patient Monitoring} & {\small VR, AI } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Laaki et al. (2019) \cite{laaki_prototyping_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small Undefined} & {\small DS } & {\small Healthcare } & { \small Surgery Robotics} & {\small Industry 4.0,AI ,VR } \\[0.4cm]
 \hline
 {\small Liu et al (2019) \cite{liu_novel_2019} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DT} & {\small Healthcare} & { \small Health Management, Elderly Health} & {\small Cloud, CPS }\\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Ross (2016) \cite{ross_digital_2016} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DT} & {\small Healthcare} & { \small Predictive Health \& Well-being} & {\small VR, 3D Modeling } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Chen et al. (2018) \cite{chen_digital_2018} } & {\small Review} & { \small Undefined} & {\small DS } & {\small Smart City } & { \small Driving} & {\small Simulation, AI } \\[0.4cm]
 \hline

 {\small Jo (2018) \cite{jo_smart_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DT } & {\small Smart City } & { \small Livestock Farms } & {\small Industry 4.0 } \\[0.4cm]
\hline

 {\small Mohammadi, Taylor (2017) \cite{mohammadi_smart_2017} } & {\small Concept } & { \small DT} & {\small DT} & {\small Smart City} & { \small Infrastructure Analysis} & {\small Simulation, VR } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Pargmann et al. (2018) \cite{pargmann_intelligent_2018} } & {\small Review } & { \small DT} & {\small DS } & {\small Smart City} & { \small Wind Farm } & {\small AR ,AI , Cloud } \\[0.4cm]
\hline
 {\small Ruohomäki et al. (2018) \cite{ruohomaki_smart_2018} } & {\small Case Study } & { \small DT} & {\small DS} & {\small Smart City} & { \small 3D Energy Mapping} & {\small Visualisation, Sensors Ontology} \\[0.4cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
%\vspace*{1mm}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Your header row seems to have 8 columns, while you have only defined 7.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is in your best interes to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Replace the final `&` symbol in the header with double-backslash.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabular` environment is set up for 7 columns. However, the header row contains an error: The `&` symbol between `{\normalsize Technology}` and `\hline`.

```
\centering \textbf {\normalsize Paper } & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Type} & 
\centering \textbf {\normalsize Defined Twin} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize 
Actual Twin} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Broad Area} & \centering \textbf 
{\normalsize Specific Area} & \centering \textbf {\normalsize Technology} & \hline
```

If you replace that instance of `&` with `\\`, and if you also replace the string `\centering \textbf {\normalsize Technology}` with `\centering\arraybackslash \textbf {\normalsize Technology}`, your code should compile.

---

I believe it's fair to say, thought, that while the code will compile, the resulting table is not particularly attractive from an aesthetic point of view. In particular, the presence of `\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}`, while assuring that the table will fit inside the width of the textblock, pretty much assures the use of an extremely small typeface and that it will thus be very difficult to read what you wrote.

I would like to suggest, therefore, that you employ a `tabularx` environment, employ varying column widths, and get rid of all vertical and most horizontal lines. Taken together, these measures will give the material a much more inviting and reader-friendly "look". Oh, and instead of flooding almost each and every cell with `\small` directives, just provide a single `\small` directive just the *start* of the `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page size parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newlength\lena\settowidth\lena{\small Defined} % col. 3
\newlength\lenb\settowidth\lenb{\small No Ex.}    % col. 4

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\small % <-- a single '\small' directive suffices

\caption{Categorical Review}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{3cm} l P{\lena} P{\lenb} l *{2}{L} @{}}
\toprule
Paper & Type & Defined Twin & Actual Twin & Broad Area & Specific Area & Technology \\
\midrule
Bilberg, Malik (2019) \cite{bilberg_digital_2019} & Case Study & DT & DS & Manufacturing & Smart Factory & Simulation  \\

Chhetri et al. (2019) \cite{chhetri_quilt:_2019}  & Case Study & DT & DT  & Manufacturing & Assembly Line & AI, Sensors, Simulation  \\

He et al. (2018) \cite{he_surveillance_2018}  & Review  & DT & DS  & Manufacturing & Power System  & Simulation, AI, Analytics  \\

Howard (2019) \cite{howard_digital_2019}  & Concept  & DT & DM  & Manufacturing & Product Development  & EDA, Visualisation  \\

Jain et al. (2019) \cite{jain_digital_2019}  & Concept  & DT & DT  & Manufacturing  & Fault Diagnosis & Industry 4.0  \\

Karadeniz et al. (2019) \cite{karadeniz_digital_2019}  & Case Study  & DT & DS & Manufacturing  & Ice Cream Machines & AR, VR, Industry 4.0, AI, CPS  \\

Kuehn (2019) \cite{kuehn_simulation_2019} & Concept  & DT & DS & Manufacturing  & Smart Factory & Simulation  \\

Lu (2019) ( \cite{lu_energy-efficient_2019}  & Review  & DT & No Ex. & Manufacturing & Smart factory & Cloud, CPS, Industry 4.0  \\

Mandolla et al. (2019) \cite{mandolla_building_2019}  & Case Study  & DT & No Ex. & Manufacturing  & Aircraft & Blockchain, Visualisation \\

Mawson, Hughes (2019) \cite{mawson_development_2019} & Case Study  & DT & DT & Manufacturing  & Energy Modelling & Industry 4.0 \\

Min et al. (2019) \cite{min_machine_2019} & Case Study  & DT & DS & Manufacturing  & Petrochemical Factory & AI, Optimisation \\

Qi, Tao (2018) \cite{qi_digital_2018} & Review  & DT & DT & Manufacturing  & Smart Factory & Industry 4.0 , AI, Cloud, Big data  \\

Shangguan et al. (2019) \cite{shangguan_hierarchical_2019} & Case Study  & DT & DM & Manufacturing  & Wind Turbine & CPS,  \\

Sivalingam et al. (2018) \cite{sivalingam_review_2018} & Review  & DT & DS & Manufacturing & Wind Turbine & CPS, Simulation \\

Tao et al. (2019) \cite{tao_digital_2019} & Review  & DT & DT & Manufacturing & Smart Factory & CPS, Industry 4.0, AI  \\

Tao et al. (2018) \cite{tao_digital_2018}  & Review  & DT & DT & Manufacturing & Assembly Line & CPS, Industry 4.0, AI \\

Xu et al. (2018) \cite{xu_digital-twin-assisted_2019} & Concept  & DT & DS & Manufacturing & Fault Diagnosis & CPS, Industry 4.0, AI, Transfer Learning  \\
\addlinespace
El Saddik (2018) \cite{el_saddik_digital_2018} & Definition  & DT & DT & Healthcare  & Patient Monitoring & VR, AI \\

Laaki et al. (2019) \cite{laaki_prototyping_2019} & Concept  & Undef. & DS  & Healthcare  & Surgery Robotics & Industry 4.0,AI ,VR  \\

Liu et al (2019) \cite{liu_novel_2019} & Concept  & DT & DT & Healthcare & Health Management, Elderly Health & Cloud, CPS \\

Ross (2016) \cite{ross_digital_2016} & Review  & DT & DT & Healthcare & Predictive Health \& Well-being & VR, 3D Modeling \\
\addlinespace
Chen et al. (2018) \cite{chen_digital_2018} & Review & Undef. & DS  & Smart City  & Driving & Simulation, AI \\

Jo (2018) \cite{jo_smart_2018} & Review  & DT & DT & Smart City  & Livestock Farms & Industry 4.0 \\

Mohammadi, Taylor (2017) \cite{mohammadi_smart_2017} & Concept  & DT & DT & Smart City & Infrastructure Analysis & Simulation, VR  \\

Pargmann et al. (2018) \cite{pargmann_intelligent_2018} & Review  & DT & DS & Smart City & Wind Farm & AR, AI, Cloud \\

Ruohomäki et al. (2018) \cite{ruohomaki_smart_2018} & Case Study  & DT & DS & Smart City & 3D Energy Mapping & Visualisation, Sensors Ontology \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table*}
\end{document}
```